# Remove a range of escape / non-printable chars in sed

Tags: regex, r, bash, unix, sed

I am working from horrible text data (2GB csv file) which includes practically all escape chars 0x00-0x1F spattered throughout the file. I attempted to read this into R for processing but cannot due to the EOFs (0x04):

```
    Warning message:
    In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
      EOF within quoted string
```

So I thought sed would be a good use to remove all the non-printable junk in the file, but there seems to be some strangeness in how to represent the escape chars in the sed syntax. I have tried all of the following which do not seem to work:

Include only specified chars:

```
    sed 's/[^a-zA-Z 0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]\\{}|;'\'':",.\/<>?]//g' IN.csv > OUT.csv
```

Identify range of non-printable in decimal or hex:

```
    cat IN.csv | sed 's/[\d0-\d31]//g' > OUT.csv

    cat IN.csv | sed s/[$'\x00'-$'\x1F']//g OUT.csv

    cat IN.csv | sed 's/\x00-\x1F//g' > OUT.csv
```

and using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to produce this:

```
    cat IN.csv | sed s/^D//g > OUT.csv
```

All the commands appear to execute, but the resulting file output does not remove the non-printable chars and appears to change the output in ways unexpected.

What I found that DOES WORK is this:

```
    cat IN.csv | sed 's/'`echo -e "\x04"`'//g' > OUT.csv
```

or this:

```
    cat IN.csv | sed 's/\x04//g' > test3.csv
```

However this only works for a single escape char. Is there a better way to address all of the non-printable chars at the same time in a single range without having to execute 1 command for each non-printable? I assume I must not be entering the syntax for a range properly.

Comment: Did you try something like `[^ -~\t\r\n]`? or `[^[:space:]!-~]`

Comment: Have you tried using the negation of the POSIX character class for printable characters: `'s/[^[:print:]]//g'` or for control characters `'s/[[:cntrl:]]//g'`?

Comment: Thanks. The 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' also seemed to work, however the file sizes between this and the [:print:] version were slightly different. I may need to investigate the differences between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removal (and transliteration) there is a better tool called `tr` (translate or delete characters). You can remove non-printable characters using:

```
cat IN.csv | tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' > OUT.csv
```

`-d` - deletes characters mentioned, `-c` inverts the ranges.

Or using the POSIX `[:print:]`:

```
cat IN.csv | tr -cd '[:print:]' > OUT.csv
```

Comment: Thanks I used the second [:print:] statement and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")}1' your_file
```

or try `sed`:

```
sed "s/[^a-z|0-9]//g;" orig_file > new_file
```

or try perl:

```
perl -pe 's/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]//g' orig_file > new_file
```

Comment: you misunderstood which characters the OP wants to remove.